# Getting the argument type of a function with template argument

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have a code that works, except the following line

```
std::is_same<first_argument<functorArgTemplated>::type,int>::value <<std::endl;  // this does not work
```

Does anybody know what kind of definitions of helper() I have to add?

The  compiler error is

```
1>d:\git\testprojekt\testprojekt\testprojekt.cpp(60): error C2065: 'functorArgTemplated': undeclared identifier
1>d:\git\testprojekt\testprojekt\testprojekt.cpp(60): error C2923: 'first_argument': 'functorArgTemplated' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'F'
1>d:\git\testprojekt\testprojekt\testprojekt.cpp(60): error C2955: 'first_argument': use of class template requires template argument list
1>  d:\git\testprojekt\testprojekt\testprojekt.cpp(22): note: see declaration of 'first_argument'
1>d:\git\testprojekt\testprojekt\testprojekt.cpp(60): warning C4552: '<<': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
```

complete code:

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename F, typename Ret>
void helper(Ret(F::*)());

template<typename F, typename Ret>
void helper(Ret(F::*)() const);


template<typename F, typename Ret, typename A, typename... Rest>
void helper(Ret(F::*)(A, Rest...));

template<typename F, typename Ret, typename A, typename... Rest>
void helper(Ret(F::*)(A, Rest...) const);

template<typename F, typename Ret, typename A, typename... Rest>
void helper(Ret(F::*)(A, Rest...) const);


template<typename F>
struct first_argument {
    typedef decltype(helper(&F::operator())) type;
};

template <typename Functor, typename Arg = typename first_argument<Functor>::type>
struct DoStuff;

template <typename Functor>
struct DoStuff<Functor, char>
{
    void print() { std::cout << "has arg" << std::endl; };
};

template <typename Functor>
struct DoStuff<Functor, void>
{
    void print() { std::cout << "does not have arg" << std::endl; };
};


struct functorNoArg {
    void operator() () {};
};

struct functorArg {
    void operator()(int a) { std::cout << a; };
};

struct functorArgTemplated {
    template <typename TArg>
    int operator()(TArg a) { std::cout << a; return a; };
};

int main()
{
    auto lambdaNoArg = []() {};
    auto lambdaArg = [](int a) {};

    std::cout << std::is_same<first_argument<functorArgTemplated>::type,int>::value <<std::endl;  // this does not work

    DoStuff<functorArg> doStuff;
    doStuff.print();

    DoStuff<functorNoArg> doStuff2;
    doStuff2.print();

    DoStuff<decltype(lambdaArg)> doStuff3;
    doStuff3.print();

    DoStuff<decltype(lambdaNoArg)> doStuff4;
    doStuff4.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `functorArgTemplated` vs `functorArgTemplateted`, looks like a typo

Comment: ah yeah, but just a copy paste typo :P
I tried it with the correct code

Comment: fix the code in the question

Comment: you can't get the address of a function template

Comment: But i should be able to get the argument type, since all input template parameters are given - or not?

Comment: "*since all input template parameters are given - or not?*", where can you see them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can answer the question "can I invoke this with an `int`" and get an answer (in the immediate context), but you cannot answer "what can I invoke this with".

In the general case answering the second question requires solving **Halt**, as what makes an acceptable argument to an object in C++ can be a Turing Complete computation.

You solved the problem for simple cases: the problem in general cannot be solved.  Solving it beyond the simplest of cases requires increasing amounts of hacks that get the answer wrong in various ways.

Usually trying to answer the question is a mixture of asking the wrong question or wanting to DRY when writing scripting/language interface code (often with languages with less ridiculous metaprogramming or type system, or an interface that narrows the type information that is transmitted).  People asking this question on SO tend to ask about their narrow issue without bothering to mention what led them down this dead end path: it is always a good idea to post a MCVE *and* a sketch of the motivating reason behind the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to test if the function has an argument at all (which may be a templated argument)?

Comment: ah yes, i would need to give template parameters in the ()-call inside the helper function.

Comment: @bodz Either pass the template arguments (but how many and what kind?  No way to tell.), and/or pass types to `()` as actual arguments (what types?).  `decltype` works better.  You very very rarely want to know "is there one argument" and not "can I pass you one `int` or one `string`?  Usually people asking this are *asking the wrong question*, and your continual asking for technical steps just makes me suspect it stronger.